# In Wordpress, how to disable admin access to adding plugins

Tags: wordpress

on WordPress website, how to disable anyone, including all admins to add new plugins. I want to be able to add plugins only via ftp, so no one can add them from WordPress menu.

Is there a custom function for this or any similar code? I searched but could not find any simple solution without any plugins that restrict access. I need solution without any extra plugin.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `functions.php` file. Get the specific users and remove their roles.

```
<?php

// Get users with this role/s.
$users = get_users( array(
    'role'    => 'administrator',
    // 'role__in' => array( 'administrator', 'editor' )
) );

foreach( $users as $user ):
    $user = new WP_User( $user->ID );
    $user->remove_cap( 'install_plugins' );
endforeach;
```

Just remember when the capability is removed then it is gone for good. If you change your mind you can use this to add the capability again.

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'role'    => 'administrator',
) );

foreach( $users as $user ):
    $user = new WP_User( $user->ID );
    $user->add_cap( 'install_plugins' );
endforeach;
```

Disable the plugins page and remove it from the menu list.

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    global $pagenow;

    remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );

    if( 'plugins.php' === $pagenow ):
        wp_redirect( 'index.php' );
    endif;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @dragi 
can i use function to stop them from access some plugin too?

add_filter('all_plugins', 'hide_plugins');

function hide_plugins($plugins) {
    unset($plugins['elementor/elementor.php']);
    unset($plugins['elementor-pro/elementor-pro.php']);
    unset($plugins['qi-addons-for-elementor/class-qiaddonsforelementor.php']);
    unset($plugins['listeo-core/listeo-core.php']);
    return $plugins;
}

Comment: In both examples you add capability.

Comment: @Snuffy you are right.

Answer (score 0):

To disable plugin installation in wordpress admin panel, the following code can be put in file "wp-config.php".

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

It can be checked, if it works.

Comment: this will disable everything: Editing themes and plugins, Installing and updating themes and plugins, and Updating the WordPress core. It is suitable for temporary use.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, add a custom function to your WordPress theme's functions.php file. This function will remove the capability to install plugins from the WordPress admin interface.

```
function disable_plugin_installation() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'install_plugins' ) ) {
        wp_die( 'You do not have permission to install plugins on this site.' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_plugin_installation' );

// Disable the "Add New" button on the Plugins page

function disable_add_new_plugin_button() {
    global $pagenow;
    
    if ( $pagenow == 'plugins.php' ) {
        echo '<style>.page-title-action, .plugin-add-new { display: none; }</style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'disable_add_new_plugin_button' );
```

Answer (score -1):

To disable admin access to adding plugins in WordPress, you can follow these steps:

- Set the default user role to "Subscriber" to restrict new users from
  accessing plugins in the admin settings. This can be configured in
  the WordPress settings.

  Alternatively, you can use custom functions to restrict plugin
  installation via the WordPress menu. Implementing such functions
  would require coding knowledge, and you can find examples on
  platforms like Stack Overflow.

Remember that these methods may vary based on your specific WordPress setup and versions, and it's crucial to have a backup before making any changes.

Comment: This doesn't full address the questions. This changes the users roles which is not with in the scope of the question.